# sql server find out first occurence and last occurence and replace them

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have written a query to fetch employee symbols for a specific date range.. which gave result like this

```
Name     Type    Date         Code
----     ----    --------      ---
Mark     Dev    25/02/2014      a
Mark     Dev    26/02/2014      b
Mark     Dev    27/02/2014      c
Mark     Dev    28/02/2014      a
Mark     Dev    29/02/2014      b
Mark     Dev    30/02/2014      c
Rob      Dev    25/02/2014      c
Rob      Dev    26/02/2014      a
Rob      Dev    27/02/2014      b
Rob      Dev    28/02/2014      b
Rob      Dev    29/02/2014      c
Rob      Dev    30/02/2014      a
Pete     Dev    25/02/2014      a
Pete     Dev    26/02/2014      a
Pete     Dev    27/02/2014      a
Pete     Dev    28/02/2014      a
Pete     Dev    29/02/2014      b
Pete     Dev    30/02/2014      c
```

I would like to replace first occurrence of 'b'[code] and last occurrence of 'b' with 'x', for each employee..

My query looks like this..

```
Select  e.Name
       ,e.Type
       ,l.Date
       ,lc.Code
  From
         Employee  e
                      Inner Join leave l on e.empid = l.empid
                      Inner Join leaveCode lc on lc.lcodeid = l.lcodeid
  order by e.identfier,l.date
```

So, How can I select all the data by replacing first and last occurrence of 'b'..

I have tried..

```
Select 
       data.Name,
       data.Type,
       data.Date,
       (CASE WHEN ((Select TOP 1 data.Date from data where data.code = 'b') = data.Date) THEN 'x'  END) AS Code
From
(Select  e.Name
       ,e.Type
       ,l.Date
       ,lc.Code
  From
         Employee  e
                      Inner Join leave l on e.empid = l.empid
                      Inner Join leaveCode lc on lc.lcodeid = l.lcodeid
  order by e.identfier,l.date) as data
```

Comment: Do you want to replace them in the table or in the query result?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply.. I want to replace them in the query result.. Im actually looking to get my result as I got my previous query but, replacing furst and last occurences of 'b' foreach employee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a `row_number()` to each row, partitioned by name, ordered by date.

This gives each row for Mark, for example, a number of 1-6.

Then you query for the `min/max` id by name `where type='x'`, and join that to the original data.

```
    declare @data table (Name nvarchar(100), Type nvarchar(10), Date date, Code nvarchar(1))

    insert into @data
    select 'Mark',     'Dev',    '2014-04-25',      'a' union all
    select 'Mark',     'Dev',    '2014-04-26',      'b' union all
    select 'Mark',     'Dev',    '2014-04-27',      'c' union all
    select 'Mark',     'Dev',    '2014-04-28',      'a' union all
    select 'Mark',     'Dev',    '2014-04-29',      'b' union all
    select 'Mark',     'Dev',    '2014-04-30',      'c' union all
    select 'Rob',      'Dev',    '2014-04-25',      'c' union all
    select 'Rob',      'Dev',    '2014-04-26',      'a' union all
    select 'Rob',      'Dev',    '2014-04-27',      'b' union all
    select 'Rob',      'Dev',    '2014-04-28',      'b' union all
    select 'Rob',      'Dev',    '2014-04-29',      'c' union all
    select 'Rob',      'Dev',    '2014-04-30',      'a' union all
    select 'Pete',     'Dev',    '2014-04-25',      'a' union all
    select 'Pete',     'Dev',    '2014-04-26',      'a' union all
    select 'Pete',     'Dev',    '2014-04-27',      'a' union all
    select 'Pete',     'Dev',    '2014-04-28',      'a' union all
    select 'Pete',     'Dev',    '2014-04-29',      'b' union all
    select 'Pete',     'Dev',    '2014-04-30',      'c'

    ;with rowid as (
         select row_number() over(partition by name order by name, date) as id,
         *
         from @data)

    select t1.*
case when t1.id=filter.minid then 'first x' else null end as [firstreplace],
       case when t1.id=filter.maxid then 'last x' else null end as [lastreplace]
    from rowid t1
    join (select min(id) as minid, max(id) as maxid, name from rowid where code='b' group by name) as filter
       on t1.name=filter.name
       and (t1.id=filter.minid or t1.id=filter.maxid)
```

[Fiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6eddb/11)

If you want the min, just take the max out of the line `and (t1.id=filter.minid *or t1.id=filter.maxid*)` and vice versa..

Comment: This query does not seem to return any 'x'`s. Am I missing something?

Comment: I figured showing him the first/last events per name, he could update it, but never hurts to add it.